# Chrome tab waits for other tab of same website to complete

Tags: google-chrome, performance

I'm not sure how this is called, so I was not able to find an answer. The thing is, when I run a website page in one tab, the other tab to a different page of that website waits until the other page is completed. In most cases, this is no problem at all.

But I find myself clicking on a command in a CMS and this page executes scripts in the background for about 5 minutes. Than it shows the results. The problem is, that all the other pages of this website are also 'loading' for 5 minutes. I can't browse the CMS website when one tab is still loading. How to avoid this?

No it's not the website that is freezing. Because I can open it in another browser and it response just fine. I always thought that tabs were really seperated processes from each other?

Answer (score 0):

- Type the following in Chrome's URL bar: **chrome://flags**
- Search for **calculate-native-win-occlusion**
- Change the dropdown to **Disabled**

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it does not seem to have any effect so far.